# How to solve Identity column increment issue when foreign key relationship violates?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship, identity-column

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have two tables, tblPerson and tblGender.

tblPerson has 4 columns

- ID
- Name
- Email
- GenderID (foreign Key)

tblGender has 2 columns

- ID
- Gender

tblGender has only two entry, male and female, having id 1 and 2.

Now, if I insert bad data to the GenderId column, like 3, 4 etc. it rejects the value but it increments the Identity column value, and when I insert another data even if it is valid, it gives the next id number.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Stop worrying about `IDENTITY` gaps](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity) - they are really **NOT** a problem! The behavior you're seeing is just the way identity columns work - and there's no easy way to "fix" this - just accept it and move on

Comment: If you *really* must prevent this from happening, then you need to **validate** the data being inserted **before** actually inserting it into the table so that this situation never occurs

Comment: don't use identity constraint , just enter data manually to ID column by getting max id and increment with one

Comment: @NazirUllah: that's really **terribly bad** advice - in a busy system with several clients connected, this ***WILL NOT WORK*** reliably! You will have **duplicates** in no time!! Do ***NOT*** do this!!

Comment: @marc_s: Really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

At first, as it was already mentioned, that is normal behavior of an `IDENTITY` column. SQL Server inserts the row first, increments Identity column value, but then rejects this row because of failed constraint.

An advice will be following:
 
1. Leave your `ID` column with gaps.
2. For very sequential 'EmployeeID' number you can use `Sequence`, which you insert from a variable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058(v=sql.110).aspx
Then you are supposed to have no gaps in your 'EmployeeID'.